# Strange behavior of Terminal PS1 value in Mac vs. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, osx

On my mac and Ubuntu I have my PS1 values set to the below:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;31m\]\d\[\e[0m\] \[\e[1;32m\]\u  \W\[\e[0m\] \[\e[1;36m\]>\[\e[0,\] \[$(tput sgr0)\]'
```

On Ubuntu the terminal prompt looks fine. But on my Mac an extra "B" is placed, like below:

```
Mon Jan 16 DrizzutoJr  ~ >B
```

I am assuming Mac and Ubuntu handle the value slightly differently. Can someone explain what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using `bash` or some other shell? I can not reproduce this with the stock `bash` on macOS (3.2.57(1)-release), nor with a later `bash` release (4.4.5(1)-release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `\[\e[0,\]` is suspect, since the enclosed text <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>**`,`**</kbd> does not correspond to a valid "ANSI" escape sequence (the comma is not a valid *final byte*).  It may happen to "work" with VTE (which has a lot of interesting cut/paste in its innards), but on other terminals, you're likely to get a stray character which will show up.

Perhaps you intended an adjacent key on the keyboard, **`m`**.

By the way, `$(tput sgr0)` is likely to produce the equivalent of **`\e[0m`** as well (using `tput` consistently throughout the expression would work as well, and though more verbose, perhaps more readable).

Further reading:

- [Is there any objective benefit to escape sequences over tput?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274453/is-there-any-objective-benefit-to-escape-sequences-over-tput)

Comment: I was just about to give Kusalananda a hint, too.  (-:  See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256449/ for the sort of advice that is being bandied about in Apple Land.

Comment: Thank you, that was correct.  Very helpful.  Can you just spell out what VTE is?

Comment: [VTE is the actual terminal emulator](https://git.gnome.org//browse/vte/) for the various "skins" known as gnome-terminal, xfce-terminal, etc.